# How to convert JSONArray which has Key Value to a Map in Java

Tags: java, gson, rest-assured

I've been able to get a Jsonarray as a response from using RestAssured. But don't know how to put it in a Hashmap with a String that shows the name of the metric and an Integer showing the corresponding value.

Response from RestAssured:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "maximum": 3.858
        },
        {
            "minimum": 5.20
        },
        {
            "number": 249
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is a Map that contains max, min & number and their corresponding values.
Ex: `{"max": 3.858, "min": 5.20, "number": 249 }`

So far I have tried the below code, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public static HashMap<String, String> getMinMaxCount(String URL, String query) {

        JsonObject res = getNewRelicAPIResponse(URL, query);
        HashMap<String, String> map = null;
        //System.out.println("Response is : " + res);
        JsonArray metricsArray = res.get("results").getAsJsonArray();
        int arraySize = metricsArray.size();
        String[] strArr = new String[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            strArr[i] = String.valueOf(metricsArray.get(i));
            //Create a Hashmap & append the Max, Min & Count
            map  = new HashMap<>();
//            String[] tokens = strArr[i].split(":");
//            String[] tokens2 = tokens[1].split("}");
            map.put("max",strArr[i]);
        }

        return map;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I did:

```
String res = ... //get response from API
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(res);
List<Map<String, Object>> list = jsonPath.getObject("results", new TypeRef<>(){});

System.out.println(list);
//[{maximum=3.858}, {minimum=5.2}, {number=249}]

Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<String, Object> mapInList : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entryOfMapInList : mapInList.entrySet()) {
        resultMap.put(entryOfMapInList.getKey(), entryOfMapInList.getValue().toString());
    }
}
System.out.println(resultMap);
//{number=249, maximum=3.858, minimum=5.2}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch !! This is what I was looking for. Cheers